# JavaScript if(x) vs if(x==true)

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript , in which cases the following statements won't be logically equal ?

```
if(x){}
```

and

```
if(x==true){}
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `x = 'test'`, as an example.

Comment: `x=' '`, `x=[]`, `x='\n'`, `x='false'`...

Comment: `x = "0"` is another

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are not at all equal.

```
if (x)
```

checks if `x` is Truthy where as the later checks if the Boolean value of `x` is `true`.

For example,

```
var x = {};
if (x) {
    console.log("Truthy");
}
if (x == true) {
    console.log("Equal to true");
}
```

Not only an object, any string (except an empty string), any number (except `0` (because `0` is Falsy) and `1`) will be considered as Truthy, but they will not be equal to true.

As per [ECMA 5.1 Standards](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2), in `if (x)`, Truthiness of `x` will be decided, as per the following table

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Argument Type | Result                                                |
|:--------------|------------------------------------------------------:|
| Undefined     | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Null          | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion). |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Number        | The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN;|
|               | otherwise the result is true.                         |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| String        | The result is false if the argument is the empty      |
|               | String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is  |
|               | true.                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Object        | true                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Note:** The last line `object`, which includes both objects and Arrays.

But in the later case, as per [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3),

```
If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
```

value of `x` will be converted to a number and that number will be checked against `true`.

**Note:**

In JavaScript, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.

```
console.log(1 == true);
# true
console.log(0 == false);
# true
```

Comment: Mean that Can the later one use string,int other of boolean?

Comment: `var x = 'a'; if (x) alert("X"); if (x == true) alert("X true");` This will only alert `"X"` and not `"X true"`

Comment: 1 is considered truthy (from ECMA 5.1: The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true)

Comment: @VitorTyburski Correct. That is why I have mentioned except 0 and 1, in my answer :)

Comment: @VitorTyburski I clarified that in the answer now. Please check

Comment: @thefourtheye all seems to be ok. But hell, js truthy values are even messier than PHP.

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting this answer, although it's bit hard to comprehend (mostly the loose-comparison rules). Guess because it's indeed messy.

Comment: I'd add rules for array to your table for completeness. I guess that any array is truthy (because it's an object) , but only non-empty arrays equal to true

Comment: @TheZver I think `object` covers all of that, doesn't it?

Comment: In JS it is , but It's not generally obvious imho.

Comment: @TheZver Fine. I included a note at the bottom of the table :)

Answer (score 0):

Several cases evaluate to false in the first form, such as empty string, 0, undefined, null.

If you want to be a bit more semantic about it, try the bang bang in front of the expression:

```
if(!!x){...}
```

this will convert the expression result to a truthy representing the same semantically. This is closer to an analogue to the expression you describe `(x == true)`

Also be aware that `==` is value comparions with type coercion, eg `"3" == 3`, whereas `===` asserts equal typing too.

So they are not the same, but often logically represent the same test, thanks to the semantics of the language and the !! you can use

Comment: Thanks. is "if(!!x)" always equal to "if(x)" ?

Comment: No no, imagine this case if(!!"hello") and if("hello" == true), the first expression will evaluate to true because "hello" is not empty string, undefined or null etc so when converted to truthy, is true. Whereas the second expression will be false, because "hello" cannot be coerced to equal the value true. http://jsfiddle.net/CEtN5/

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in the question. I meant comparison with if(x)

Comment: Ok I see your edit. Essentially you are testing the same thing with if(!!x) and if(x), its just the value of !!x is guaranteed to be true or false, whereas if(x) only works because the language evaluates certain conditions to be true/false, as mentioned earlier, 0, empty string, null, undefined.. which aren't strictly truthy, but can be logically interpreted as such

Comment: so, to clarify , the following statements are all absolutely equal ? if( x ) , if( !!x ) , if( !!x == true ) , if( !!x === true )

Comment: they will all evaluate to the same thing, so in that sense they are equal... under the hood their efficiency varies I'd imagine