# Is it bad practice to utilise JavaScripts "truthiness"?

Tags: javascript

Underscore.js has two methods `_.isNull` and `_.isUndefined` which we use a lot in our code and we've also created a mix-in for `_.isUndefinedOrNull`.

I recently realised that I could easily use javascripts "truthiness" to achieve the same results most of the time so the question is, is that considered bad practice?

What's better?

```
if(someVariable){...}
```

or

```
if(_.isNull(someVariable) || _.isUndefined(someVariable){...}
```

Comment: They're not equivalent so there isn't a better one...

Comment: `if (someVariable == null)` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both are entirely different.

```
if (someVariable)
```

will evaluate to falsy, if `someVariable` is `0` or `false`. So it is better to have explicit checks in this case. You might like to check the truth table in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061950/1903116) which shows when a variable will be evaluated to either truthy or falsy.

Answer (score 1):

> I recently realised that I could easily use javascripts "truthiness" to achieve the same results most of the time

If only most of the time, then your solution doesn't work. Use `if (someVariable == null)` instead to test for either undefined or null.

> so the question is, is that considered bad practice?

Not necessarily. If you know that all the possible values for `someVariable` other than the `null`/`undefined` you want to test for are truthy (e.g. objects), then it's fine.

If they can be primitive values, it's usually a mistake except your condition explicitly wants to test for the falsy values of the respective type. In your null-comparison case it would a mistake.